# "Call to undefined function fivestar_widget_form()" error

Tags: rating

I am getting the following error - it's related to the fivestar module. As far as I can tell, it is using an obsolete function call (used in Drupal 6)

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function fivestar_widget_form() in /home/SITENAME/public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/views_php/plugins/views/views_php_handler_field.inc(202) : runtime-created function on line 5
```

The problem is that I've looked at all references to the widget in the template files, tried to change them.

I've tried the following, as said [here](http://drupal.org/node/1114726), but I keep getting the error.

```
print render(fivestar_widget_form($node));
print render($content['field_vote']);
print drupal_render($content['field_vote']);
print drupal_render(fivestar_widget_form($node));
```

What could be causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function called `fivestar_widget_form()` in the Drupal 7 version of Fivestar (I've just grepped the module folder).

It's likely that function is a CCK hook remnant, CCK having been incorporated into the core Field module in Drupal 7, and all of it's functions renamed.

As far as I know there's no easy way in Drupal 7 to use a field widget form as a stand-alone form so you might have to look for another way around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might help if you still need it - I was just running into the same issue, banging my head against the wall until I finally found the solution (for me). For some reason, the Fivestar field had gotten set to hidden under full content in "Manage Display" for my content type. I'm pretty sure it defaulted to this, even though the "Default" display did not have it hidden. When I changed it to display "As Stars", I could use

```
print render($content['field_vote']);
```

in my node--*.tpl.php file.

Comment: The OP is asking why he gets an error about a not existing function.

Comment: Right, so my answer may not be the correct answer to his stated question. But, I found this original post when I was searching for that error, and it appeared I had tried similar things as the OP, so thought I would share how my situation was resolved in case it's helpful for others out there.